# custom report for stripe transfers

Tags: stripe-payments

I need to figure out a way to generate a report from Stripe from transfer events. Every time there is a "transfer.created" event, I want to see the list of charges included in that transfer - each on a separate row of the report. I am not a developer, but an end-user looking for some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for you to export that data would be through the API. In other words, you need your developer to do it for you.

One way of handling it would be to respond to the transfer.created webhook. When that event is triggered, you store the pertinent data in your website's local storage. You would then have (presumably secure) web ui that makes the data request and formats the data for viewing/printing/exporting.

Alternatively, and perhaps more easily (but with limitations), your report page could simply make an api call to the [Stripe_Transfer::all()](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_transfers) function.

The biggest limitation to the latter method is the Stripe-imposed 100-records-per-request limit. The benefit of the first method is that you have complete control over sorting, filtering, searching, purging, etc.